# Can I programmatically prevent a 400 Error from being thrown due to cookie size?

Tags: c#, iis-7.5

My team maintains a suite of C# applications which all share a common set of cookies.

Recently, we had a situation where the cookie size became too large and users began experiencing a 400 error when accessing our production site.

I wrote a little webforms app that would iterate through a list of our cookies and delete them which did not include our shared code that would try to read/write the cookies in Global.asax:

```
            foreach (var c in cookieList)
            {
                HttpCookie currentUserCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[c];
                if (currentUserCookie != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(c);
                    currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
                    currentUserCookie.Value = null;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie);
                }
            }
```

However, all the pages on our site still threw the error.  The only solution we could find was to have the users manually delete their cookies.

Is there any we can trigger a deletion of our cookies from the server side and save our users the hassle of manually clearing their cookies?  We're using IE11 and Chrome 54.

Answer (score 0):

this line try update existing cookie (it removed from response)

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie);
```

try this..

```
        foreach (var c in cookieList)
        {
            HttpCookie currentUserCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[c];
            if (currentUserCookie != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(c);
                currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(currentUserCookie);
            }
        }
```